# How to convert Json arrays to integer from string in Java script

Tags: javascript, java, json

In my application I will get a Json string from server (java). 
When I retrieve the Json in Java script what I get is

```
var data =  [{"value":"3","label":"17 hr"}
 {"value":"2","label":"18 hr"},
 {"value":"1","label":"19 hr"}]
 }]
```

What I want is

```
var data = [{"value":3,"label":"17 hr"},
 {"value":2,"label":"18 hr"},
 {"value":1,"label":"19 hr"}]
 }]
```

That is value column is retrieved as strings instead of integer values. How to retrieve them as integers? What is the best or optimal way to do the same?

Comment: You should make sure they are numbers when you generate the json in your server.

Comment: ...and Javascript is not so fussy about numbers being strings. Are you? Why?

Comment: From server it is integers. They are numeric values. Bt in js i got them as strings.

Comment: I use them in d3 js where I get error as invalid param. I have tried in both these formats 2nd format works and the 1st is not working. That is why I asked this question

Comment: Try to parse the object to JSON with JSON.parse(obj)

Comment: People don't come to conclusions that the question is stupid or absurd. This is a valid question I think.

Comment: If you are using D3, just use a `forEach` and convert the strings to numbers with `+d.value`.

Comment: Infact, you can parse to integer your string, I think this is your solution

Comment: I am already using the same.  Json.parse(response.responseText)

Comment: Is that supposed to be valid JSON?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: shouldn't the fix be in server side (java code) ?

Comment: *"From server it is integers"* .. not if server is wrapping in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data =  [{"value":"3","label":"17 hr"},
 {"value":"2","label":"18 hr"},
 {"value":"1","label":"19 hr"}]

// if you want to keep the data var untouched
var parsedData = data.map(function(item) {
  // make sure you don't change item's reference by returning new object
  return {
    value: parseInt(item.value, 10),// you will end up with NaN if item.value is not a number
    label: item.label
  };
});

// if you don't care about mutation
data.forEach(function(item) {
  item.value = parseInt(item.value, 10)
});
```

Comment: No need to map it to new array...just fix original if that's all OP needs

Comment: Force of habit (doing FP + Immutability) ... No mutations ... (you can simply do a forEach and mutate the original array, your call.